# Play y pause en un mismo boton en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

lo que tengo es un codigo que al presionar un boton reproduce una cancion y si el usuario vuelve a darle se pause, todo con un mismo boton. Solo que sale un error de :

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

```
let click=0;
function playMusic() {
    click=click+1
    console.log(click);
    let audio = new Audio;
    audio.src = "nameSong.mp3"
    audio.play();
    if(click==2){
        audio.pause();
        click=0;
        return click
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios inconvenientes con tu código:

- Cada vez que se llama a `playMusic()` intentas crear un nuevo elemento de audio. Si esto funcionara, no solo terminarías con múltiples elementos creados a la vez, sino que nunca vas a pausar uno de los creados anteriormente, pues no guardas ninguna referencia a ellos ni haces búsquedas.
- El elemento de audio, luego de su creación, toma algún tiempo para poder comenzar a reproducir el audio, básicamente el tiempo necesario para *descargar* los primeros segundos del *stream* que va a reproducir, por lo que la llamada a `play()` podría fallar y definitivamente no tendría sentido llamar a `pause()` sobre un objeto que no se está reproduciendo.

  Los elementos que heredan de [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), como el `HTMLAudioElement` creado al llamar a `Audio()`, tienen una serie de propiedades con las que puedes evaluar su estado actual, si se está reproduciendo, etc. No me baso en ellas para la *solución* a tu pregunta, para no complicar las cosas, sino que dejaré el mecanismo de la variable `click` (terrible nombre para una variable por cierto), solo para mantener esto lo más simple posible.
- Olvidaste poner los paréntesis en la llamada a `new Audio();`
- Te falta el `;` en la línea donde asignas la propiedad `src` del nuevo audio.
- La lógica del `if` está incompleta, pues siempre llamas al método `play()` y, cuando `click` tiene valor 2, inmediatamente llamas a `pause()` (sobre el mismo audio al que acabas de llamar al método `play()`. Esto es lo que provoca el error que ves... pero ese error es secundario, como creo que ha quedado claro con esta explicación.

Tratando de aplicar correctivos a estos problemas, lo que hago es:

- Crear un único elemento de audio al comenzar (ojo con los `()` y `;`).
- Al inicio de la rutina `playOrPause()` evalúo la propiedad [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) para determinar si ya está listo el control de audio para comenzar a hacer *play*/*pause*. Si no lo está, se sale de la rutina sin cambiar el valor de `isPlaying`.
- Si hubiese algún error, lo obtengo al evaluar la propiedad `error`, que, de estar asignado, nos devuelve un [`MediaError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaError)
- Finalmente, la rutina entra a la lógoca para hacer *play*/*pause*, como entiendo que deseas.

```js
let isPlaying = 0;
let audio;
console.log("creando audio");
audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "Nicholas%20Gunn%20-%20Nature.mp3"

function playOrPause() {
  if (audio.readyState < 2 /*HAVE_CURRENT_DATA*/) {
    console.log("no está listo aún");
    if (audio.error) {
      console.log("error : " + audio.error.code + " -> " + audio.error.message);
    }
    return(0);
  }
  isPlaying = isPlaying + 1;
  console.log(isPlaying);
  if (isPlaying == 1) {
    audio.play();
    console.log("playing");
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    console.log("paused");
    isPlaying = 0;
  }
  return(isPlaying);
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="playOrPause()">¡hazme clic!</button>
```

Comment: ya quedó, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Significa:

1. Si el audio está pausado: if(x.paused)
2. Estará en play: x.play()
3. Si no: else
4. Estará pausado: x.paused(); [Su estado normal]

```js
function btn(){
var x=document.getElementById("aud");
if(x.paused){
x.play()}
else{
x.pause();
}
}
```

```html
<audio id="aud" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" controls=""></audio>
<br><button onclick="btn()">Play/Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice claramente que tu solicitud fue interrumpida por llamar a pause().
Está entrando dentro del if que tienes ejecutando audio.pause(), o audio.pause() lo tienes en otro lado que hace que se esté ejecutando, Sería bueno que intentaras mostrar un poco más tu código